# pyWriteDynamicFrame: Unrecognized scheme null; expected s3, s3n, or s3a [Glue to Redshift]

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

While executing a Glue Job, after the necessaries transformations I am writing the results of my Spark `df` to a Redshift table like this:

```
dynamic_df = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glue_context, "dynamic_df")

glue_context.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(
    frame=dynamic_df, catalog_connection=args['catalog_connection'],
    connection_options={"dbtable": args['dbschema'] + "." + args['dbtable'], "database": args['database']},
    transformation_ctx="write_my_df")
```

But I am receiving this exception:

```
19/08/23 14:29:31 ERROR __main__: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1572375324962_0001/container_1572375324962_0001_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
return f(*a, **kw)
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1572375324962_0001/container_1572375324962_0001_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o190.pyWriteDynamicFrame.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized scheme null; expected s3, s3n, or s3a
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was missing the parameter `redshift_tmp_dir` in the function `from_jdbc_conf` as reported in [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-writer.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-writer-from_jdbc_conf).

So the functions now is:

```
glue_context.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(
    frame=dynamic_df, catalog_connection=args['catalog_connection'],
    connection_options={"dbtable": args['dbschema'] + "." + args['dbtable'], "database": args['database']},
    redshift_tmp_dir="s3://my_bucket/my/location/", transformation_ctx="write_my_df")
```

Comment: That documentation link you provided, states "redshift_tmp_dir – An Amazon Redshift temporary directory to use (optional)." So how does missing an optional parameter cause trouble?

Comment: @user1113782 I only stated the behaviour, don't know the reason. Besides it was posted almost 2 years ago, it might be that the issue has been fixed since then and made the parameter optional. Just if you receive this error message, try using this solution